# How were Greek patronymics stressed in Latin?

Tags: names, stress, loanwords

According to Wikipedia, the Scipios (as in Africanus) were known collectively as the *Scīpiadae* rather than the *Scīpionēs*. This was a rather poetic Greek way to say "sons of Scipio", as in the *Atreïdae* (sons of Atreus).

In Latin, following the penult rule, this name would be pronounced *Scīpíadae*. But in Greek, it would be *Scīpiádae*.

Do we know which of these pronunciations was used? In other words, do we know if the people who affected Greek-style names also pronounced them the Greek way?